# Basic API with HTML: Creating Objects

Tags: json, html, api, object

I have a pretty simple calculator that I am trying to setup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>Crypto Currency Diversifier</p>
<div class="container">
<h1>Crypto Currency Diversifier</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
   Dollars:<br>
  <input type="text" name="dollars" value="500"><br><br>
  # of Currencies:<br>
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="20"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The next step is I need to pull the top 20 (quantity) cryptocurrencies, then divide the 500 (dollars) between them relative to market cap.

Here's the API website: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Clicking on https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10 shows me the top 10 currencies.

How can I ADD up all the market caps of each individual currency on the page. Then create ratios from them?

- Math part is pretty straightforward, what I don't get is how to actually pull the data from the API link and get it in a workable format.

Comment: Lookup query and ajax. Take a moment to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Jquery and Ajax:

You can implement this like this:

```js
function getCurrencies()

{
  $.ajax(
  {url:"https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=20",
     success:function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                var totalcap=0.0;
                var u=$("<ul>");
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    var currency=data[i];
                    var cap=parseFloat(currency["market_cap_usd"]);
                    var li=$("<li />").html(currency["name"] + " " + cap.toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i && c !== "." && ((a.length - i) % 3 === 0) ? ',' + c : c;
}));
     
                    u.append(li);
                    totalcap+=cap;
                }
                $('#currlist').html('').append(u);
                $('#cap').html(totalcap.toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
    return i && c !== "." && ((a.length - i) % 3 === 0) ? ',' + c : c;
}));
                $('#data').val(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("Error");
            },
            dataType:"json",
            type:"get"}
  
  );

}
```

```css
textarea {width:600px;height:250px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>Crypto Currency Diversifier</p>
<div class="container">
<h1>Crypto Currency Diversifier</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
   Dollars:<br>
  <input type="text" name="dollars" value="500"><br><br>
  # of Currencies:<br>
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="20"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getCurrencies(); return false"
>
  Total Market Cap:<div id="cap"></div><br />
  Currencies: <div id="currlist"></div><br />
  <textarea id="data"></textarea>
</form>
```